# How to create a new client id for a web app to use google cloud endpoints

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to use google cloud endpoints from my web app.

I did "Web Client Tutorial", but I stopped while creating a client id.

I followed this step, but I can't see "Registered apps" in the step 3.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/getstarted/clients/js/add_auth#registering_a_web_client

The following screenshot is what I see in my Developers Console.
[image: There is no "Registered apps"]

I guess this description is obsolete, but I can't find out a new way.

I tried "Credentials" -> "CREATE NEW CLIENT ID".
In the next form, I chose "Web Application" as application type, set the domain of my web app as "Authorized Javascript origin", but I am not sure what should I set as "Authorized redirect URI".

Could anyone tell me how I can create client id?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

They changed the UI recently but not the docs. On the upper left you can see that "Cloud End Point tu..." is already selected... Tapping that would lead you to the list of apps.

Comment: Thanks.
Actually I could do that by the following step.
1. Select "API and auth" then "Credentials"
2. Click "NEW CLIENT ID"
3. Choose "Web Application" as Application Type, set "https://(my app id).appspot.com/" as Authorized Javascript origins, and leave Authorized redirect URI then click "Create Client ID".